# Running pytest with separate test files

Tags: python, pytest

I have a directory structure as recommended by [the pytest good integration practices guide](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html), which looks like this:

```
.
src/
    mypkg/
          __init__.py
          mypkg.py
tests/
      __init__.py
      test_mypkg.py
```

The `__init__.py` files are both empty, and the other files are as follows:

### `mypkg.py`

```
def foo(x):
    """
    Show x.
    >>> foo(5)
    x is 5
    >>> foo("hello")
    x is hello
    """
    return "x is {0}".format(x)
```

### `test.py`

```
from mypkg import *
def test_foo():
    assert foo(5) == "x is 5"
```

When I run `pytest` from the root directory I get:

```
tests\test_foo.py:1: in <module>
    from mypkg import *
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypkg'
```

What is the recommended way of setting this up?

Answer (score 1):

I am no pytest specialist but this looks like a mission for conftest.py, conftest allow one to load tests from module / package / shared fixtures and more...

See [this page](https://docs.pytest.org/en/2.7.3/plugins.html?highlight=re#conftest-py-local-per-directory-plugins) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

py doesn't know the path of mypkg.py . So you need to inform that using below two lines

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/src/mypkg")
```

Comment: It's bad practice to change the python path by hand.